# Design advice concerning creation of context menu

Tags: android, sms, htc-android

If someone have an HTC device and go to the SMS messages and tap on some of the messages in the thread then an context menu is shown.

I have an list and I do not know what is the right thing to put the context menu to be shown on longpress or just on press (click) on some of the item in the list.

I think that the right thing is to put it on long press, I mean the user holds some of the items in the list and then it is presented with the options...

Well the sms in htc it is not coded this way. When I open messages that ware send to some friend and tap on some specific message then I am instantly presented with the list of options, sms i app that is frequently used by many people and htc is big company, so they did this by some reason. Reason I do not get it :(, can someone tall me what is the right thing ?

showing context menu should be done:
-on long press
-on clcik

maybe my question is stupid, but I want to know what is the convention and what is more user friendly
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well...I would say that it depends on the content of the list. Is there any specific action that you can describe as being default? If there is something you intuitively would expect your list to do if you click an item, you should really use that one for simple click and defer the context menu to long click.

I can't tell you what htc's idea behind their decision was, but that's how I see it. Basically it's all about intuition. If there are several things that can be done and they all are equally likely, just have the user decide what he wants.